# How to display ul as inline-block?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, html-lists

How to align bottom menu in one row, no matter what screen size is? I tried to put `display: inline-block`, but it's not working on my side.

Here's the CSS

```
footer #middle-footer{
 background: #F6F6F6;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 50px 0 10px 0;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}
.bottom-menu ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 letter-spacing: 0.19px;
 font-size: 14px;
 }
.bottom-menu ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.8;
}
.footer-mobile-version{ display: inline-block; }
```

Here's the link, http://mobiletest.me/sony_xperia_z2/2569987

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `<li>` tags rather than the `<ul>` tag.

#### Example

```
.bottom-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

## Edit

Looking at the link that you provided, I can see that the padding of the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` tags are taking up too much room so that the text will not fall "inline". It also doesn't help that the surrounding `<div>`'s width is not making full use of available screen space.

#### Example

```
.bottom-menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom-menu ul li a {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i already have `display: inline-block;` in `.bottom-menu ul li` but it's not working

Comment: i follow your example, but the space between menu item is too big and the menus are not aligned, here http://mobiletest.me/apple_ipad_air/2569987

Comment: @User014019 You will of course have to accommodate for different screen sizes yourself. The example CSS that I wrote was just to illustrate my point. At least now - going back to your original question - the links are inline with each other.